# Kurento emiting hanging video frames while using composite element

Tags: video, webrtc, kurento

I'm using composite element to send audio stream and screen share video stream to all connected user. When I'm emitting only audio it is working fine but when i'm trying to emit screen share video stream through composite element the video get hanged after some time or if video continues to running frame are coming too late (the delay would be in minutes).

Is it a good idea to use composite element in sending video streams of screen share as I have read in the answer of my previous question regarding composite element/ mixing media stream that using mixing media streams would toll to CPU usage as some processing is involved in mixing media stream?

Comment: Did you check the CPU load in your KMS when you get the delays?

Comment: No I didn't check the CPU usage but there should be no load to the machine as at that time only two users are connected to KMS one is sending its screen sharing and audio and another one is receiving those media. And its an Amazon ec-2 machine.

Comment: Check it just in case. CPU load of the composite is not negligible, as it must decode and encode the streams back again. Also, it's not only the number of clients, but the size of the video the clients are sending.

Comment: Any news on this? Can you share an update?

Comment: Yes, I tested my CPU usage on amazon-ec2 (m3-medium) machine and the CPU usage goes to 100%. When I connected only 5 users to stream audio using composite element and in that only two of them are sending their audio rest of all are receiving it.

Comment: Composite is a CPU intensive operation, as the mixing is done in raw. For that purpose, each stream must be decoded, and then encoded back again for sending.

Comment: @AkshayRathore - were you able to resolve issues with connecting more than two users. what was the cpu configuration anduration ram configof AWS server you were using? I am facing similar issue of scalability.